# How to send requests from React on firebase https to API on Golang on DigitalOcean?

Tags: reactjs, go, ssl, https

I've set up an API on Go and deployed it to DigitalOcean. On server, I generated certificates with these commands:

```
SERVER_CN=my-digital-ocean-address
openssl genrsa -passout pass:1234 -des3 -out ca.key 4096
openssl req -passin pass:1234 -new -x509 -days 3650 -key ca.key -out ca.crt -subj "/CN=${SERVER_CN}"
openssl req -passin pass:1234 -new -x509 -days 3650 -key ca.key -out ca.crt -subj "/CN=localhost"
openssl genrsa -passout pass:1234 -des3 -out server.key 4096
openssl req -passin pass:1234 -new -key server.key -out server.csr -subj "/CN=${SERVER_CN}"
openssl req -passin pass:1234 -new -key server.key -out server.csr -subj "/CN=localhost"
openssl x509 -req -passin pass:1234 -days 3650 -in server.csr -CA ca.crt -CAkey ca.key -set_serial 01 -out server.crt
openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -nocrypt -passin pass:1234 -in server.key -out server.pem
```

So the server is running correctly, and I was able to send requests from Postman. But I don't know how to set up certificates on my React frontend, as it says

> The certificate key "/ssl/server.key" is invalid. Passphrase required
> for encrypted key

Thanks in advance, any help is really appreciated! (as I spent too much time on it)